# Best Programming Practice

Tags: java

I have some validator classes such as ABCValidator, PQRValidator, XYZValidator etc. All these classes contain only single static boolean method which takes single parameter and validate it.

For Example of ABCValidator class:

```
class ABCValidator {
    public static boolean isValid(abc){
        //abc validation logic
        //return true/false
    }
```

}

Is there any anti-pattern exists in above code ? 
Rather than above approach, if we centralize all the methods in to one helper class, do we have any side effects ? 
Is there any other approach to do in a better way ?

Comment: I would personally not use static methods if you are looking to create a "validator" mini-framework. This will allow your validator objects to operate and use validator state. Also, you can take advantage of generics to create a generic interface which would be implemented by all sub-classes. As always, it's a good idea to draw inspiration from existing frameworks: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html

Comment: How do you select the correct validator? That is probably the anti-pattern.

Answer (score 2):

I would create an interface:

```
public interface Validator<T> {
  public boolean validate(T object);
}
```

Then create classes that implement this interface. This will allow using the polymorphism trait and also will be easier to create tests, especially if the `validate` method does something that is more than computation like going out to a DB or web-service.

Comment: You could also make this a generic interface so different types can be used. Or make the validate method take an Object as type.

Answer (score 1):

I would look at how others have solved similar problems; for example,
http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html

I'd prefer generics as suggested by Sanjay in question comments, and use interface as suggested by Avi in his answer. In fact, do read about how to use function objects to represent strategies in the book Effective Java. And maybe about lambdas if you are into java 8.